# Is this 3D graphic and is there any farther information?

Tags: javascript, colors, properties, pixel

I coded this none HTML5 render html application to improve cross platform graphics and I came up to this type of coding. I can't continue by my own because that farther steps requires skills that I do not have yet.
https://plabsfill.com/gif/2021/september/PmL_0_9_8.gif
Is this 3D graphic and is it known by anyone? If so, what if I have to do a cube or square? Can anyone tell?

Comment: Thanks for your question, but it looks like you are searching for a solution, not an answer. so please share some code, that you have tried so far.

Comment: The application assigns dynamic attributes to dom object pixels changing their position, color and properties.

Comment: I change dynamically the attributes of x and y to for example x=cos((i)/6.4)*120+400 and y=sin((i+o)/6.4)*120+280 and it will resulte of a circle form rotating as in 3D motion. Is this the way of begining 3D programming in javascript?